# Unresolved external symbol DXGetErrorStringA

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

```
// Graphics.cpp

#include "Graphics.h"
#include "dxerr.h"
#include <sstream>    

std::string Graphics::HrException::GetErrorString() const noexcept
{
    return DXGetErrorString(hr);
}

std::string Graphics::HrException::GetErrorDescription() const noexcept
{
    char buf[512];
    DXGetErrorDescription(hr, buf, sizeof(buf));
    return buf;
}
```

DXGetErrorString and DXGetErrorDescription give this error respectively:

```
1 unresolved external symbol DXGetErrorStringA referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Graphics::HrException::GetErrorString(void)const " (?GetErrorString@HrException@Graphics@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
2 unresolved external symbol DXGetErrorDescriptionA referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Graphics::HrException::GetErrorDescription(void)const " (?GetErrorDescription@HrException@Graphics@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
```

```
// Graphics.h

#pragma once
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <string>

class Graphics
{
public:
    class Exception : public ExceptionHandling
    {
        using ExceptionHandling::ExceptionHandling;
    };
    class HrException : public Exception
    {
    public:
        HrException(int line, const char* file, HRESULT hr) noexcept;
        const char* what() const noexcept override;
        const char* GetType() const noexcept override;
        HRESULT GetErrorCode() const noexcept;
        std::string GetErrorString() const noexcept;
        std::string GetErrorDescription() const noexcept;
    private:
        HRESULT hr;
    };
    class DeviceRemovedException : public HrException
    {
        using HrException::HrException;
    public:
        const char* GetType() const noexcept override;
    };
}
```

I don't know if this helps but I am using dxerr (with DXGetErrorString.inl, DXGetErrorDescription.inl and DXTrace.inl) for error handling, i don't know if this is the best way as I am not an expert in this field.

Comment: I expect you have to link to an additional library `dxerr.lib`

Comment: There's a bit more to the story of DXERR than the 'you are just missing the lib' . See [Where's DXERR.LIB?](https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/)